# Role delete and Role remove commands are not working | Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I made a role remove and role delete command that, idk what happened to it. It was working fine but the bot doesn't respond neither does it remove/delete the role. I might have messed it up while working on other commands, since everything else works fine but when I searched up online solutions. All the results were the same as my code. Not sure what's happening.

Role delete command:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def roledelete(self, ctx, *, role: discord.Role):
    await role.delete()
    await ctx.send(f'"{role}" got yeeted')
```

Role remove command:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def roleremove(self, ctx, roles, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
      member = ctx.message.author
      guild = ctx.guild
      role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=f"{roles}")
      await member.remove_roles(role)
      await ctx.send(f"{roles} role has been removed")
```

Comment: are they indented well in the cog class? and do they show up in default help command?

Comment: yes they are, and it does show up in the default help command.

Comment: What is your discord.py version, was the code working before you updated the discord.py?

Comment: Yes its up to date, I use repl.it btw, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

For roleremove, you are running the code to remove a role from a member if member == None. If a member is specified there is no code to remove the role from the user. This should fix that

```
@commands.command()
async def roleremove(self, ctx, roles, member: discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
        pass
    else:
        member = ctx.message.author
        guild = ctx.guild
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=f"{roles}")
        await member.remove_roles(role)
        await ctx.send(f"{roles} role has been removed")
```

There is no problem in roledelete so the issue must be elsewhere in your code.

Comment: It doesnt work, It sends a response saying that the role has been removed but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

the question was only meant for remove not delete command lol. Anyways, so I removed a variable and replaced some of the code on my remove command and it worked. I spent a whole day trynna figure out how to do this and the solution was as simple as this lol. Here's the code if anyone needs it:

```py
  @commands.command()
  async def roleremove(self, ctx, roles, member: discord.Member=None):
      role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=f"{roles}")
      await member.remove_roles(role)
      await ctx.send(f"{roles} role has been removed")
      if member == None:
        await ctx.send("Ok I'll remove roles but from who tho??"
```